# create an interactive map of a campus for an ipad app

Tags: ipad

i want to create an interactive map of a campus for an ipad application , i am having trouble where to start from and i have no idea , i am a newbie in ipad programming , do anybody now link to any tutorials of somekind that would help me to start making maps on ipad.
any help will be deeply appreciated , thanking you for the help

Comment: Custom UIView is what you're looking for. You can change it to your desires and use events to make it react to touches, swipes etc..

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want/need to accomplish: have you considered building a WebApp instead of a native one? If it needs to be a native iPad App, how about implementing the campus map as HTML + JavaScript and present it in a UIWebView? That would make the map reusable across a multitude of devices. Going the full Web route has the added benefit of being able to push updates instantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my product, MapsAlive. It now supports iPad and iPhone. You can see lots of examples at http://www.mapsalive.com.